# Easy way to style the rows of a jQuery UI DataTable?

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, datatables

I am trying to style a jQuery UI DataTable.  I have found the different classes that get inserted such as "odd" and "sorting_1".  Right now, in order to change the styling, I am just overriding these in a separate stylesheet.

Is there a better way to change the default styling of the rows?

I don't think the rows are covered by ThemeRoller.

I'm not sure this will matter, but I am doing this in Rails 3.1.0 using the jquery-datatables-rails gem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQueryUI to style it. See http://datatables.net/styling/themes. And you can manually edit the datatables css files if you don't want to 'override' them.

Comment: I think that is using ThemeRoller and it doesn't change the coloring/style of the rows.

Comment: What exactly do you want to change about the rows?

Comment: Don't forget if you do use Themeroller to set the bJquerUI to true in the datatables call. It will change the color of the rows.

Comment: I have bJQueryUI set to true. Which ThemeRoller settings do I change to modify the table row colors?